# getting Null Pointer Exception in android on setOnClickListener

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting Null Pointer Exception in button.setOnClickListener why i don't know. i just check all xml file and other stuff but still getting any one can please resolve my problem.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button bLearn_Basic_C_Programs;
Button bC_Programs;
Button bMoreApps;

String thepixelmakerWebSiteAddress ="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.c_programs_start);


    bLearn_Basic_C_Programs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLearn_Basic_C_Programs);
    bC_Programs             = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bC_Programs);
    bMoreApps               = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMoreApps);



    Log.d("here", "first");
            // i getting exception here
    bLearn_Basic_C_Programs.setOnClickListener(this);
    Log.d("here", "second");
    bC_Programs.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMoreApps.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View view) {

      switch(view.getId()){

      case R.id.bLearn_Basic_C_Programs: 

          Intent intent1 = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Learn_Basic_C_Programs_Start.class);
          this.startActivity(intent1);
           break;

      case R.id.bC_Programs:

          Intent intent2 = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, C_Programs_Start_1_50.class);
          this.startActivity(intent2);
          break;

      case R.id.bMoreApps:
          Intent intenMoreApps = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(thepixelmakerWebSiteAddress));
          startActivity(intenMoreApps);
          break;
      }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that your c_programs_start layout includes R.id.bLearn_Basic_C_Programs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that findViewById really isn't finding the button. My guess is that either, c_programs_start is incorrect or your id's are incorrect.

In the future, you should try to paste the xml as well for these sorts of questions.

Comment: still getting same exception

Comment: sorry i resolve the problem thanks for your cooperation. ya you are right findViewById isn't finding the button